# setText is not working in android

Tags: android

I have this code to add data in corresponding database.

```
 public class RegisterActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    SQLiteOpenHelper helper;
    SQLiteDatabase dbs;
    Button reg,exit;
    EditText eid,ename,eno,ecourse;
    TextView efee;
    CheckBox java,net,php,and;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        eid=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etid);
        ename=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etname);
        eno=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etmob);

        efee=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.etfee);
        efee.setText(""+ 0);

        java=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.tvjava);
        php=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.tvphp);
        net=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.tv_net);
        and=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.tvand);



        reg=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tvreg);
        exit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tvcan);


        reg.setOnClickListener(this);
        exit.setOnClickListener(this);

        java.setOnClickListener(this);
        helper=new SQLiteOpenHelper(this,"AMS",null,1) {



            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                db.execSQL("create table Reg_Student(_id integer primary key autoincrement,name text,contact integer,java text,net text,php text,andr text,fee integer)");
            }


            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


         };
        dbs=helper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        int fees=0;
        if(v == reg)
        {

            //ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put("name",ename.getText().toString());
            cv.put("contact",Integer.parseInt(eno.getText().toString()));


            if(java.isChecked())
            {

                fees = fees + 5000;
                efee.setText(String.valueOf(fees));
                cv.put("java",java.getText().toString());
            }

             if(php.isChecked())
            {
                fees = fees + 2000;
                efee.setText(String.valueOf(fees));
                cv.put("php",php.getText().toString());

            }

             if(and.isChecked())
            {
                fees = fees + 4000;
                efee.setText(String.valueOf(fees));
                cv.put("andr",and.getText().toString());
            }

             if(net.isChecked())
            {
                fees = fees + 5000;
                efee.setText(String.valueOf(fees));
                cv.put("net",net.getText().toString());
            }

            cv.put("fee",fees);

            long id = dbs.insert("Reg_Student", null, cv);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Registered with id : "+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            reg.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }


    @Override
         protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    helper.close();
   }
   }
```

Here,data is getting added in database,but setText is not getting changed when I select a particular textbox.

I am new to android,so kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: please post the code for the whole activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `efee.setText(Integer.toString(fees));` to (use this way) `efee.setText(""+fees);`

`efee.setText(""+fees);` is working whatever your datatypes.

**Edited:**

if you want to show fees before register then use this way:

```
chkIos = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkIos);

    chkIos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
                //is chkIos checked?
        if (java.isChecked()) {
            efee.setText(""+fees);
        }

      }
    });
```

[how use checkbox in android](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/).

Comment: I have already tried this too.It displays correct value when i click on register button.But I want that if i select java,it should display fees in text box,but it displays after clicking the register button which is wrong.

Comment: but i want to add these values to database too.and fees variable is common for all checkbox.So if i use anonymous class,there is a problem with variable fees & COntentValues object.

Comment: make global variables in your activity

Answer (score 1):

use this way, first chnage int to string then set on text view

```
efee.setText(String.valueOf(fees));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(php.isChecked())
    {
        fees = fees + 2000;
        efee.setText(Integer.toString(fees));// Problem is in this line.
        ...
```

Change it to

```
efee.setText(String.valueOf(fees));
```

> **Update** //adding code to setText onChecked

```
   //in onCreate()

   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.javaCB);

   cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if(isChecked)
            {
                fees = fees + 2000;
                efee.setText(String.valueOf(fees));
            }
        }
    });
```

Similarly you can set other CheckBoxes. Note: you must make efee accessible inside this method. so declare it in the beginning itself.

Comment: I have already tried this too.It displays correct value when i click on register button.But I want that if i select java,it should display fees in text box,but it displays after clicking the register button which is wrong.

Comment: the code is inside Onclick method, so the change will appear after clicking only right?

Comment: ya...right....what can i do to display fee in text box whenever a checkbox is clicked?

Comment: Welcome. Looks like you accepted almost the same answer from another user. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as the one below

```
    if (php.isChecked()) {
        fees = fees + 2000;
        efee.setText(fees+"");
```

The reason - If you specify a Integer, Android will consider it be a reference to a resource, like R.string.somevalue.

So you need to specify it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Well,I assume that your java is a CheckBox.
Then you need to add a OnCheckedChangeListener to your java component

```
java.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){ 
        @Override 
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
        { 
            if(isChecked)
            { 
                fees = fees + 5000;
                efee.setText("" + fees);
                cv.put("java", java.getText().toString());
            }
        } 
    });
```

Comment: I am using object of cv to add other values such as name,contact no . to add to databse.So i cant use the same object of content values in an anonymous class & similarly,i cant use fees variable in that. I hope u r getting my point.